# Python Pandas count values and create summary dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF that contains multiple events for multiple customers.
The important columns are:

| Customer | Result |
| --- | --- |
| cust1 | OK |
| cust1 | OK |
| cust1 | FAIL |
| cust2 | OK |
| cust2 | FAIL |
| cust2 | FAIL |
| cust3 | OK |
| cust3 | OK |
| cust3 | OK |

I need to convert this to a summary dataframe like:

| Customer | FAIL | OK | SUCCESS_RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust1 | 1 | 2 | 66.6 |
| cust2 | 2 | 1 | 33.3 |
| cust2 | 0 | 3 | 100 |

Looks simple enough, but can't find the right approach.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['Customer'], df['Result'])
new_df['SUCCESS_RATE'] = new_df['OK'] / new_df.sum(axis=1) * 100
new_df = new_df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
  Customer  FAIL  OK  SUCCESS_RATE
0    cust1     1   2     66.666667
1    cust2     2   1     33.333333
2    cust3     0   3    100.000000
```

Comment: Every time when I see a solution to my pandas problem I am shocked how short and simple are they :)

Comment: When you’re in the realm of things pandas does well, there is often a simple solution. Thankfully this is one of those times. =)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to reshape the dataframe, and then call [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add new column as `SUCCESS RATE`:

```py
result =(df.pivot_table(index='Customer', 
                        columns='Result', 
                        values='Result', 
                        aggfunc='size',
                        fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .assign(**{'SUCCESS RATE' : lambda row: round(row['OK'] * 100 / (row['FAIL'] + row['OK']), 2)})
     )
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
Result Customer  FAIL  OK  SUCCESS RATE
0         cust1     1   2         66.67
1         cust2     2   1         33.33
2         cust3     0   3        100.00
```